# Members users are not able to share a site with External users

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, share, external-users, links

I am working on sharepoint online tenant, and i am unable to allow member users to share the sites with external users.
here is what i tried:-

1. inside the tenant we are allowing external sharing + anonymous linking.
2. inside the site collection access request we have the following:-

[image]

3. now i login as a member user >> click on share icon from the home page >> type the email of an external user (user with Hotmail account, who have never access the site collection).
4. now the Hotmail user received and email,but when he clicks on the site collection link inside the email, he will get the following error:-

[image]

5. so i logout from the current user Hotmail, and i went to the SP online site collection using the site owner user, click on invitations, where i found the invitation with 2 options (resend + withdraw), so i chose to resend:-

[image]

6. so the Hotmail user received another email, but this time when he click on the site collection link , he got this error:-

[image]

so what is causing the external user to not being able to access the site collection?

second question, why inside the site collection invitations, the site owner can not approve the request, he can only resend or withdraw !!! and should the site owner approve the site collection sharing request which was initiated by the member user???

Answer (score 1):

If you share site with external user he has to accept the invitation, there is no matter of approval.Whether you are a member or owner you will not see approve option